# how Write a text on png image Using python PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to code for make a registration System and Identity Card printer first form done with making data import to database using sqlite3 database and tkinter GUI.this form for get data from database and write that data text on png image.that png image after written data it is the identity card.

**so this is the problem..code run without any errors.but image not written data.for try this code firstly i didn't use database data.i used data from string variable **

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Canvas
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

connection = sqlite3.connect("school.db")

tao = Tk()
tao.title("Mayurapada Central Collage")
tao.configure(bg = '#6699ff')
canvas = Canvas(tao,width = 600,height = 400,bg = '#6699ff')

def imgs():
  img = Image.open("C:\\Users\\TAO\\Desktop\\New\\02.png")
  #img.show()
  str01 = "Hello World"
  font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf",200)
  w,h = font.getsize(str01)
  print(str01)

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text(((900-w)/2,(900-h)/2),str01,font = font,fill = "black")
img.show()


button01 = Button(tao,text = "Preview",bd = 7,padx = 5,pady = 5,command = 
imgs).place(x = 50,y = 300)

canvas.pack()
tao.mainloop()
```

Comment: have a look [here](https://haptik.ai/tech/putting-text-on-image-using-python/)

Comment: Surely `img` and `font` are only known inside `imgs()` function and not in main program?